# Getting app containing framework containing OpenCV into TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, frameworks, testflight

I find myself in a situation which may be unique.  Please be patient, because this is going to be complex.

I am charged with creating for iOS 1) an SDK, which has taken the form of a framework , 2) a demo application, and 3) a reference application.

The SDK uses OpenCV, and so the OpenCV framework is automatically embedded inside it.

The project for the demo application at compile time automatically builds the SDK and includes a copy within itself.  The demo application also links directly to the copy of OpenCV within the SDK.

The reference application is an example application meant to show people how to use the SDK framework.

So far all of this somehow works.  <TAKE A BREATH>

The latest version of the demo application, however, has a problem.  I need to get a copy of it into TestFlight.  Despite it working fine on actual iPhones AND Xcode archiving it with no problems, nothing I have done has gotten it all the way through the App Store/TestFlight submission process.  The furthest I've managed is to coerce it is that it got through validation, but when I tried submitting the app, after uploading Xcode complained:

> ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle
>   'org.opencv' at bundle path
>   'Payload/FakeName.app/Frameworks/FakeNameIOSSDK.framework/opencv2.framework'
>   is not signed using an Apple submission certificate."

I have indeed verified that OpenCV (at least version 2.4.9 downloaded from the Website OpenCV.org) is not signed.  I made an attempt to sign OpenCV with codesign, but I couldn't make that work.

The question is:  What do I need to change to make the App Store happy enough that I can get my app into TestFlight?  Is there some way to hide the lack of code-signing of OpenCV?  Is there a way to get OpenCV properly code-signed such that the App Store is happy with it?  (I have a strange vision of compiling the source of OpenCV directly into my SDK, but the size and complexity of OpenCV is such that I'd rather not try such a thing except as a measure of last resort.)

Alternatively, I find myself wondering about whether it is workable to not embed OpenCV in my SDK, but embed it within the app instead.  This is what I did with the last release of the demo app in TestFlight.  However, when I created the reference app, the system failed to work, leading to the current oddity of a framework within a framework.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Why don't you build and sign OpenCV yourself?

Comment: I did try that.  OpenCV 2.4.9 refused to build properly in Xcode 6.3.1 running on Mac OS X 10.10.3, at least using OpenCV.org's installation instructions.

Comment: Have you ever gotten this to work? I'm faced with the exact same issue.